# set up 301 redirect within wp-content/uploads/ directory of a WP site to a new image URL

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I need to do a redirect within `wp-content/uploads/` - to a new image name, because the old one doesn't work. How do you do this?

I want to redirect from `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/image-1.png` to `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/image-2.png` - I tried using both of our 301 redirect plugins ([Yoast](https://yoast.com/), and [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)) but neither worked.

I also tried changing `.htaccess` to this from (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-cant-redirect-file-under-wp-content/):

```
# ...stuff above

# END WordPress

RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/image-1.png https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/image-2.png

# ...stuff below
```

But it didn't work.

How do you do this?

Comment: I wonder what it means that the old image doesn't work

Comment: And what do you mean exactly when the redirect "didn't work"? What response do you get? Any error? A WP 404 response? An Apache 404 response? Or something else?

Comment: to clarify 404 nginx

Comment: "nginx"?! How does Nginx fit into your config? Nginx does not use `.htaccess`. And to clarify, the original image (ie. `image-1.png`) does not exist on the filesystem?

Comment: idk sorry I'm mostly Front End I don't really do or understand server side.

Comment: I just get 404 with an <hr> and under it it says nginx

Comment: You need to clarify your server config. Are you using Nginx as your only server? Or are you using Nginx as a front-end caching proxy in front of Apache and Apache is your application server?

Comment: Did the old image (`image-1.png`) used to exist and it was later deleted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129589/discussion-between-kawnah-and-mrwhite).

Answer (score 1):

If this image does not exist then the request will be rewritten to the WordPress front-controller before your redirect occurs.

Try the following instead using mod_rewrite at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/2021/09)/image-1\.png$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/image-2.png [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string simply avoids having to repeat the full URL-path. (`$1` contains `wp-content/uploads/2021/09` - captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.)

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 301, but only once you have tested that it works as intended in order to avoid potential caching issues.

---

Alternatively, you can create an additional `.htaccess` file at `/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/.htaccess` - which will override the parent `.htaccess` file and allows you to "simplify"<sup>***1**</sup> the directive. For example:

```
# /wp-content/uploads/2021/09/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/[^/]+$
RewriteRule ^image-1\.png$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/image-2.png [R=302,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains the URL-path leading to the image file (captured from the preceding *CondPattern*).

(<sup>***1**</sup> Ok, that's debatable.)

---

> **UPDATE:** to clarify 404 nginx

*tl;dr* you'll probably need to contact your host (WPEngine) to get to the bottom of this.

You could either have one of two scenarios (probably the second). Either:

1. You are on an Nginx server, so `.htaccess` files do not apply. You would need to perform this redirect in WordPress itself (eg. using a plugin). However, the plugin(s) you have tried do not appear to be working (I assume you are getting the same 404 nginx response), which leads me to believe it you have #2
2. You are on Apache, but there is an Nginx front-end proxy sitting in front of Apache that is configured to serve static content (from `/wp-content/uploads`). The request for these resources (or this area of the filesystem) is handled entirely by Nginx. The request does not even reach Apache/WordPress, which is why you are seeing an Nginx generated 404 response.

   The Nginx proxy needs to be configured to allow requests through to Apache so you can implement the redirect (or the redirect would need to be implemented directly in the Nginx server config, which you probably don't have access to?). This probably requires a support request with the host.

Comment: Thanks for commenting and the assist but this doesn't work sorry

Comment: I still get a 404

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility you're running a CDN?

I was trying to create re-directs through a WordPress Plugin (AIOSEO) and had issues with it being a 'protected source'.

Some additional research led me here. Since I use Cloudflare CDN on my websites, I started looking through Cloudflare's settings and found their manual redirect.

I had to first create a redirect list, that had the list of 301 (or other) redirects, and then a re-direct rule to enable the list.

My guess is other CDN providers have it but I would be unsure if it's available through proprietary CDNs that hosts offered or 'free' plans.

Hopefully this helps. It fixed my issue with 404 on images and not being able to redirect using 301 due to protections of some sort.